# What guitar technique is Steve using in the video?

Tags: guitar

In the beginning of the video at around 0:07 he appears to have slapped the sixth string and played the fifth string at the same time(at least that’s how you do it according to the tab he provided) how is this possible? Can someone please help me out?
Here’s the video

Here’s the tab with the part in question marked red
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the tab shows a muted string, the x, and another note played at the same time on the next string down. This can be done in several ways but here it looks like he is muting the note with his thumb on his fretting hand. One would assume he’d then strike both strings with his picking hand but I don’t see that happening. Could be what we hear, what we see, and what is written aren’t all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Those Xs are not representing what's being played. The notes are clear, and may be considered staccato, but muted? No.

Answer (score 1):

The tab doesn't match the video.

A correct tab for this note would be:

```
---
-0-
-0-
-0-
---
-x-
```

He makes the percussive sound on the bottom string using the thumb, while strumming the three open strings with other fingers.